# showing rows in a combo box

Tags: c#, sql

I need to show some rows ofa database that I have and show them inside a combo box.

I've this piece of code that is working but instead of showing the correct rows it just shows `System.Data.DataRow`.

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting1"];
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            string sqlQuery = @"SELECT CDU_ESTADOS  from  testetiposdestados";
            MessageBox.Show(sqlQuery);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(table);
            comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);

        }

    }
```

Here is a screenshot of what the combo box shows:

[image]

And here what the combo box should show:

[image]

If you have any question about the code or something else feel free to ask

Comment: Have you defined combobox ValueMember and DisplayMember?

Comment: I didnt do that in the DataGrindView and it worked

Comment: A ComboBox is not a DataGridView. You need to define the DisplayMember and ValueMember when using a data binded combo box.

Comment: @ZoharPeled And how should I do that?

Comment: `combobox1.DisplayMember = "CDU_ESTADOS"`

Comment: @ZoharPeled I should add that before or after the connection with the database?

Comment: As far as I remember, you need to do it before setting the combobox's `DataSource` property.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the combobox `DisplayMember` property.
Otherwise it just displays the value returned from the `ToString()` of the data items (in this case, `System.Data.DataRow`):

```
combobox1.DisplayMember = "CDU_ESTADOS";
```

To put in context of your code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting1"];
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT CDU_ESTADOS  from  testetiposdestados";
        MessageBox.Show(sqlQuery);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);
        combobox1.DisplayMember = "CDU_ESTADOS";
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
    }
}
```

btw, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, and also `DataTable` all implements the `IDisposable` interface - so you should use them with a `using` statement.
Also, I would suggest start using the `var` keyword for local parameters, it will make your code shorter and more readable:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting1"];
    var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
    using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        var sqlQuery = @"SELECT CDU_ESTADOS  from  testetiposdestados";
        MessageBox.Show(sqlQuery);
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using(var table = new DataTable())
                {
                    da.Fill(table);
                    combobox1.DisplayMember = "CDU_ESTADOS";
                    comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```